# I was recently told that running my RV 50 feet away from my breaker box would cause a 30 amp appliance to use 60 amps of power. Is that true?

Tags: power

Will the length of cable cause an appliance to use or require more amperage?

Comment: Please *edit your question* so that the title is a title, and both parts of your question are in the question.  I suggest "effect of cable length of power draw" as a title.

Comment: Pah, humbug! You might waste power, yes, but under no sensible circumstances would that double the amount of current that flows. Anyway, this question is "can someone debunk this random nonsense I was told without reason", and just taking a look at the amount of nonsense youtube electronics videos, I don't think that's a role we want to fulfill. Questions here must show a minimum amount of engineering-level research and display the reasoning behind a statement to be checked.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a yes or no hypothetical question with a weak premise and little detail. You could probably find a scenario with a combination of loads, distance, poor selection of cable, poor motor protection, incorrect branch circuit protection and whatever that might approach the stated result, but this site is not intended for that kind of game.

Comment: 60A is not a measure of power, so .. no.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not true.

A long power cable will cause some voltage drop, which may cause electric motors to draw a little extra current.  If the cable size is appropriate for the current draw and length, the voltage drop in the cable should stilll leave an acceptable voltage in your RV.

Comment: "__voltage drop__ may cause electric motors to __draw a little extra current__" huh?! could you, please, explain this to me?

Comment: https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html?material=copper&wiresize=3.277&voltage=120&phase=ac&noofconductor=1&distance=50&distanceunit=feet&amperes=30&x=50&y=21

Comment: @BruceAbbott I know what voltage drop is. What I don't know, is how it can cause motors to draw _extra_ current. My understanding is that it will make motors generate less power, that's it.

Comment: @Maple sorry that wasn't directed at you. Depending on the type of motor it may draw more current at lower voltage eg. induction motor, constant load that needs more current at lower voltage.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Ah, I see. Yes, some loads might indeed adapt to the lower voltage by drawing more current. Or there could be a regulator/booster in the circuit which will do the same. Frankly, I have no idea what RV appliances are, never been in one.

Comment: @Maple can also be true of series wound (universal) motors heavily loaded, which can bog down and stall at low voltages when they would run fast and efficient at higher V.